# sqlplus called from shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a problem calling SQL commands directly from a shell script. My shell script contains the following commands:

```
set x = `sqlplus -S $ISLK_ORACLE_UID` <<EOF

delete from rc where rcd_id = 1 ;
update rcd set standard = 'Test_DB7' where id = 1 ;
delete from rc where rcd_id = 2 ;
update rcd set standard = '700' where id = 2 ;
delete from rc where rcd_id = 5 ;
update rcd set standard = 'DB7' where id = 5 ;
delete from rc where rcd_id = 998 ;
update rcd set standard = '2001-2050' where id = 998 ;

delete from rc where rcd_id=3004 ;

begin
for fd_rec in (select * from fd)
loop
   insert into rc values(1008, 1, fd_rec.id, 'islk.am@swisscom.com') ;
end loop ;
end ;

commit;

EOF
```

The single commands (delete, update) are completed without any problems, but thw loop seems not to be performed (nothing inserted after statement). Has anybody an idea what the problem might be?

Thanks a lot in advance
Best wishes
Jörg

Comment: fd table contains some rows?

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your loop with a single SQL statement:

```
insert into rc select 1008, 1, id, 'islk.am@swisscom.com' from fd;
```

This is (to me) more readable and more efficient, given that it uses no PL/SQL and loops, but simply relies on pure SQL.

Comment: Great, this works. But I would though be interested in why PL/SQL does not work properly in this way.

Comment: Maybe you are simply missing the '/' after the pl/sql block?

Comment: Your are right. I am just migrating my database from RdB to Oracle; with RdB the / was not necessary, so i forget it all the time.
Thank you four your help